# Unable to deploy war file build from Intellij Idea

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I developed Struts 2 web application using IntelliJ Idea. Now I tried to deploy war file build from IntelliJ Idea to Tomcat Server installed in google compute engine. While deploying war file tomcat server throw error "Bad Gateway, The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server." and war file not deployed.

I tied with other war file build using Netbeans IDE and It deployed without any errors

Here is my artifact details.
[Arifact Detils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1KP1.png)

Is there any solutions for this problem

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't sound like an error due to the WAR file, it seems to have to do with some proxy settings.  Can you check if the WAR file from IntelliJ runs locally on Tomcat without issue?  If so, then check your proxy settings.

Comment: I think its error in WAR. No, that WAR file throws an error in local Tomcat server. Because I installed another WAR build by NetBeans without error.

Comment: Then fix the problem locally and retry in the cloud.

Comment: you should paste the tomcat logs in your intellij idea console or the log file